# Getting the maximum similarity of a phrase compared to phrases of another string

Tags: javascript

Using the `similarity` function below I can check the similarity of the two given string for instance:

```
similarity("Japan exhibitionz", "Japanese exhibition"); // returns 90% for instance
```

But I want to get the similarity between a **given phrase** and a **string** so that the most similar part of the **string** being compared with the **given phrase**!!

let's have a look at this sample code:'

```
const phrase = "Japan exhibitionz";
const string = "there is a Japanese exhibition of contemporary prints in Japanese teritory where Japan is";

function getSimilarity() {
    I want to get the result same or as near as possible as the result of: similarity("Japan exhibitionz", "Japanese exhibition")

}
```

I don't want to compare the phrase with string like this: `similarity(phrase, string);` this gives us a very poor similarity score...

I want to return the maximum similarity of a substring inside `string` compare to `phrase`

Here is the similarity function I'm gonna use:

```
function similarity(s1, s2) {
    var longer = s1;
    var shorter = s2;
    if (s1.length < s2.length) {
        longer = s2;
        shorter = s1;
    }
    var longerLength = longer.length;
    if (longerLength == 0) {
        return 1.0;
    }
    return (longerLength - editDistance(longer, shorter)) / parseFloat(longerLength) * 100;
}

function editDistance(s1, s2) {
    s1 = s1.toLowerCase();
    s2 = s2.toLowerCase();

    var costs = new Array();
    for (var i = 0; i <= s1.length; i++) {
        var lastValue = i;
        for (var j = 0; j <= s2.length; j++) {
            if (i == 0)
                costs[j] = j;
            else {
                if (j > 0) {
                    var newValue = costs[j - 1];
                    if (s1.charAt(i - 1) != s2.charAt(j - 1))
                        newValue = Math.min(Math.min(newValue, lastValue),
                            costs[j]) + 1;
                    costs[j - 1] = lastValue;
                    lastValue = newValue;
                }
            }
        }
        if (i > 0)
            costs[s2.length] = lastValue;
    }
    return costs[s2.length];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could potentially use the number of words in the phrase as a proxy:

```js
const phrase = "Japan exhibitionz";
const string = "there is a Japanese exhibition of contemporary prints in Japanese teritory where Japan is";

const numWords = phrase.split(' ').length
const splitString = string.split(' ')

const similarityPairs = splitString.map((_, i) => similarity(
  phrase,
  splitString.slice(i, i + numWords).join(' ')
))

const maxSimilarity = Math.max(...similarityPairs)
```

I don't know what kind of assumptions you are safe to make about your data, however. For instance, this solution won't be a good fit for, say, unexpected whitespace in an otherwise-similar substring.

Comment: This works like crazy thanks.. I don't get your meaning "unexpected whitespace in an otherwise-similar substring"!!!

Comment: you're welcome :) what i meant by that comment was that say the phrase is "potato chips" and the longer string is "i want to eat pot a to chips", it's going to trip up on those extra spaces in "potato", because the space is exactly what it's using to detect words